# I try data from file(ascii) in to table but it show wrong result

Tags: php, html, list, file, explode

i try that file into array and then explode it as list but it alway wrong the result bcuz it have wrong data when i explode it will have blank(" ") how i can solve it?

my file looklike this [myfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M0jZT2aHPs-RR62XowgABpl75YMIRHoX/view?usp=sharing)

```
RAW: the raw SAMI1 series. NORM: the normalized SAMI1 series.   The value of 99.99 is undefined.
RAW    RAW    RAW    RAW    RAW   NORM   NORM   NORM   NORM   NORM
Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep   JJAS    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep   JJAS
1948  3.115  3.930  3.754  1.974  3.193  1.613  1.547  2.593  1.813  2.504
1949  2.425  3.608  2.905  1.975  2.728 -0.148  0.671  0.131  1.816  0.812
1950  2.473  3.852  2.929  1.605  2.715 -0.027  1.334  0.199  0.793  0.761
1951  2.655  3.067  2.849  1.145  2.429  0.439 -0.796 -0.032 -0.475 -0.277
1952  2.744  3.430  2.973  0.871  2.504  0.666  0.188  0.326 -1.234 -0.004
1953  2.453  3.473  2.892  1.064  2.471 -0.077  0.307  0.092 -0.699 -0.126
1954  2.846  3.510  3.160  1.986  2.876  0.926  0.405  0.870  1.846  1.347
1955  2.920  3.047  3.007  1.776  2.688  1.116 -0.851  0.426  1.266  0.663
1956  2.663  3.491  2.897  1.561  2.653  0.459  0.355  0.107  0.674  0.538
```

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa4Oc.png)
and mycode as

```
     <?php
  $n=0;
  foreach ($lines as $row) {
    if ($n!=0) {
      //list($RAW1,$RAW2,$RAW3,$RAW4,$RAW5,$NORM1,$NORM2,$NORM3,$NORM4,$NORM5) = explode(' ',$row);

      if ($n<=2) {
        //echo strpos($row,"NORM");
        if ($n==1) {
          $string = substr($row,43);
        }elseif($n==2) {
            //echo strrpos($row,"Jun");
            $string = substr($row,44);
        }
        //echo $string;
        list($NORM6,$NORM7,$NORM8,$NORM9,$NORM10)=explode('   ',$string);
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $NORM6; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $NORM7; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $NORM8; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $NORM9; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $NORM10; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
      }else {
        //echo strpos($row,"1.614");
        $string = substr($row,42);
        if ($n<=5) {
          echo strlen($string)."<br>";
          list($NORM6,$NORM7,$NORM8,$NORM9,$NORM10)=explode(' ',$string);
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $NORM6; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $NORM7; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $NORM8; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $NORM9; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $NORM10; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
        }

      }
    }
    $n++;
 }
 echo substr($lines[5],42);
 ?>
```

Comment: Please include an example of the file data as text within the question.  It's particularly helpful to do that so that when someone reviews this question in the future (looking for a similar answer) they can see what the data was, rather than going to a link that potentially won't be active anymore

Comment: i try a lot but the result in web and my file dont show same result sry for that

Comment: exploding this at single space characters, will get you an empty string in the result in all places where you have _two_ consecutive spaces in your input data. Try `preg_split` with a pattern like `/\s+/` instead, and the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag.